# Git Rebase behavior

Tags: git, rebase

I know there are many questions about git rebase but I am still having issues with it after two weeks of trying to wrap my head around it.

**Scenario:**

Nonprod Branch:

```
New code to push to production
```

Production Branch

```
Production code waiting for an update from non-prod
```

We are getting ready to push nonprod code to production.

We now have an urgent hotfix to apply to production.

```
git checkout production
git checkout -b hotfix_for_prod
<do some changes>
git add ...
git commit ....
git push ...
<Merging hotfix_for_prod with Production branch>
```

Now..

Nonprod Branch:

```
New code to push to production
```

Production Branch

```
Production code waiting for an update of non-prod
Hotfix
```

We want to rebase non-production from production but we are getting some very strange results, conflicts that do not exist in the current state of Nonprod or Prod. We tried:

```
git checkout Nonprod
git pull
git checkout -b nonprod_rebase_prod
git rebase production
<Strange results in many files that do not match Prod OR Nonprod branches>
```

**Edit** The strange behavior displays conflicts in a file where the two commits that made changes to the file are not either the production head or the nonproduction head. The commits must be commits further back but we do not want the result of either.

We then tried this:

```
git checkout production
git pull
git checkout -b prod_rebase_nonprod
git rebase nonprod
```

We get exactly the result we were expecting. This makes no sense to me. I would assume that since Nonprod needs the data in prod that when we rebase nonprod from prod, the changes in prod will be in nonprod in the history, we can't even solve the merge conflicts because they make no sense

When we rebase nonprod into prod we get the result we wanted but it makes no sense. How can you rebase a child branch onto the parent branch when the parent is the origin? Do we then merge this branch off of production with nonprod?

Can someone explain this?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: First of all, you can merge which has less duplicated conflict resolution. You need to show how the conflict in rebase in weird, or there would be no answers.

Comment: Are you sure that the history of the `nonprod` branch is linear? Because, if it's not, trying to rebase `nonprod` on anything else will linearize the history, leading to unexpected merge conflicts. It is the asymmetry of the results that gets me thinking into this direction: `production` seems to have linear history, so no conflicts here. Anyway, I second what @TatsuyukiIshi said: Merging is generally significantly supperior to rebasing. Use merge if you can.

Comment: There is not enough information in your posting. One thing we need is (enough of) the output of `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to show the various commits' state before you run `git rebase`. That will help demonstrate which commits `git rebase production` will copy, as well as the point in the graph where it will append the copies.

Comment: Do I want to rebase non-prod from production based on the way the data was included or do I want to rebase production from nonprod?